# Checking a username and password from a text file

Tags: python

I'm trying to create an authenticator with python to add into another project.

Here is my code:

```
# User authentication
global authenticated

def checkAuth():
    global authenticated
    authenticated = False
    # User enters their username and password
    username = input("Enter your username: ")
    password = input("Enter your password: ")
    username = username.strip()
    password = password.strip()

    for line in open("users.txt","r").readlines():
        line = line.strip()
        loginInfo = line.split(",")
        print(loginInfo)
        if username == loginInfo[0] and password == loginInfo[1]:
            print("Authorised")
            authenticated = True

isAuth = checkAuth()

if (isAuth):
    input("Authorised \t Press any key to continue: ")
else:
    input("no auth")
```

When I run my code and enter a correct username and password the if statement inside the checkAuth function evaluated to true, but the if statement at the bottom doesn't get the True value.

These are the two username and password combos in the users.txt file.

[users.txt file](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GFaaF.png)

Comment: Read https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/ for tips on how to debug your code.

Comment: I hope this is just a "toy" example, and you don't intend to use it in a project that's exposed to the internet that actually needs any form of security.

Comment: @PM2Ring it is for a school programming task, it wont be exposed to the internet.

Comment: I am afraid that using commas to separate username and password may fail your code if comma is present in username or password.

Comment: @BlackThunder that is a very good point. You could always use a regex pattern to check for password validation in that case. Something like `^[^,]*$` will reject any password with a comma

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You either need to do `if(authenticated)` or instead of setting authenticated to true, just `return true`. Your `checkAuth()` function is void, so it has no return value. Using globals for this isn't a good idea.

If you're absolutely sure you want to use a text file for this, try this:

```
def isAuthorized():
  username = input("Enter your username: ").strip()
  password = input("Enter your password: ").strip()

  with open("users.txt", "r") as f:
    for line in f:
      loginInfo = line.strip().split(",")
      if username == loginInfo[0] and password == loginInfo[1]:
        return True
    return False

if isAuthorized():
  input("Authorized \t Press any key to continue: ")
else:
  input("no auth")
```

Using a text file for this provides no security whatsoever so keep that in mind. The problem with a global boolean is that you have to reset it after each login or it will remain true even if the wrong information is given.

Answer (score 3):

you need to return a value from the `checkAuth()` function

```
checkAuth()
   ...
   ...
   return authenticated
```